# How should I interpret the "null check pattern" in C#

Tags: c#

I have some code that effectively does this:

```
    private void DoStuff(int? a)
    {
        int c = 0;
        if (a is int b)
        {
            c = b;
        }
    }
```

But `a is int b` gives me a warning:

> Use not null pattern instead of a type check succeeding on any not-null value

Using Resharper's suggestion "Use null check pattern" autocorrects this code as follows, causing the warning message to disappear:

```
   private void DoStuff(int? a)
    {
        int c = 0;
        if (a is { } b)
        {
            c = b;
        }
    }
```

That's great and all but now I don't understand the code I'm writing. How should I interpret `if(a is {} b)` in the english language?

Is it saying "if `a` is not null set `b` to `a`'s non-null value"?

Or is `{}` a shorthand for "the underlying type of `a`" (i.e. `int`)?

Is there anything I can put inside the braces, or do the braces alone have their own meaning?

Anything to help me understand what this code really means would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Resharper is being stupid. Your code was already correct.

Comment: @madreflection, that code produces the correct result does not mean that it is optimal. I would imagine that checking for null is more performant than checking the type, in which case the suggested option is better because it produces the same result with better performance. The performance difference would be negligible unless the code was repeated many times but that doesn't make it stupid to suggest it.

Comment: @John "I would imagine that checking for null is ..." measure, don't speculate.

Comment: Here's a R# ticket for this issue. Please vote it up: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-493361

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `a is { }`  is an example of using `is` to match an expression against a pattern... [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)

> The is operator checks if the result of an expression is compatible with a given type. For information about the type-testing is operator, see the is operator section of the Type-testing and cast operators article.

> Beginning with C# 7.0, you can also use the is operator to match an expression against a pattern, as the following example shows:

```
static bool IsFirstFridayOfOctober(DateTime date) =>
    date is { Month: 10, Day: <=7, DayOfWeek: DayOfWeek.Friday }
```

---

The `a is { } b` is an example of using a declaration pattern to declare a new local variable, scoped to the `if` block. [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/patterns#declaration-and-type-patterns)

> You use declaration and type patterns to check if the run-time type of an expression is compatible with a given type. With a declaration pattern, you can also declare a new local variable. When a declaration pattern matches an expression, that variable is assigned a converted expression result

---

I highly recommend [Sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AsgBQCU+hxTjRAvi+hwA4BOAlgDcAhgBcAppgoARAPYBlEQFcAZsup8AdiID86IbQ4EkTJppHoAxugC86AAwBuDqeXpqQ9HwDO+dK3QARgbGJkRGoaFWtgFOIaHscX7IrEA==) to investigate the optimisations that take place during C# compilation. In your provided example:

```
private void DoStuff(int? a)
{
    int c = 0;
    if (a is { } b)
    {
        c = b;
    }
}
```

Equates to:

```
private void DoStuff(Nullable<int> a)
{
    int num = 0;
    int valueOrDefault = default(int);
    int num2;
    if (a.HasValue)
    {
        valueOrDefault = a.GetValueOrDefault();
        num2 = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        num2 = 0;
    }
    if (num2 != 0)
    {
        num = valueOrDefault;
    }
}
```

So basically `a is { } b` is saying; does `a` match any pattern (i.e. not null) if yes, assign it to a local variable `b`.

---

Personally I think that whatever code you write should be as readable as possible for everyone. If you are confused by the code you have written then don't write it, write something that the person taking over from you will understand.

Comment: `{ } myVar` is basically non-null `var myVar`

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR resharper is incorrect, official language reference suggests `if (a is int b)`. Anyway `if (a is int b)` and `if (a is { } b)` are compiled into exactly the same CIL.**

---

The Resharper suggestion seems to be incorrect, even the official language reference for nullable value types ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#examination-of-an-instance-of-a-nullable-value-type)) literally shows an example with `if (a is int valueOfA)`:

```
int? a = 42;
if (a is int valueOfA)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"a is {valueOfA}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("a does not have a value");
}
// Output:
// a is 42
```

Even the official language reference for `is` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/is)) operator shows:

```
int i = 34;
object iBoxed = i;
int? jNullable = 42;
if (iBoxed is int a && jNullable is int b)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a + b);  // output 76
}
```

Also if you inspect [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language), it's compiled in .NET 7 into the very same thing. See for yourself [here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LglgNgNAJiDUAfAAgJgIwFgBQyDMABGgQMIEDeOB1RhyALAQLIAUAlBVTd19QL68CggA4AnMADcAhsACmRRgBEA9gGVgAVwBmW9CzAA7YAH4CUtoMrZu3Q8AIBjAgF4CABgDcg21oIspBGAAzhR8BABGFtY21FYxMU6u4V7RMQKpBOk8GWKSMvIMBCrq2lqo+kam5pbeNHaOLu4p8YG+/oEh9ZG1sT02iRHN8Vk06XxAA=).

`if (a is { } b)`:

```
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 0
        IL_0003: stloc.0
        IL_0004: ldarga.s a
        IL_0006: call instance bool valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
        IL_000b: brfalse.s IL_0018

        IL_000d: ldarga.s a
        IL_000f: call instance !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
        IL_0014: stloc.1
        IL_0015: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0016: br.s IL_0019
```

vs. `if (a is int b)`:

```
        IL_0000: nop
        IL_0001: ldc.i4.s 0
        IL_0003: stloc.0
        IL_0004: ldarga.s a
        IL_0006: call instance bool valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
        IL_000b: brfalse.s IL_0018

        IL_000d: ldarga.s a
        IL_000f: call instance !0 valuetype [System.Runtime]System.Nullable`1<int32>::GetValueOrDefault()
        IL_0014: stloc.1
        IL_0015: ldc.i4.1
        IL_0016: br.s IL_0019
```

Comment: +1 for doing the research, but, frankly, "incorrect" is a too strong of a word here. It's a suggestion, so you can disable it or ignore it. It's exactly as arguable as using ternary instead of ifs TBH.

Answer (score 0):

Would that `a` have been of type `object`, then the `if (a is int b)` check would be fine and I don't think Resharper would have complained. However, now `a` has type `int?` (or `Nullable<int>`) so the check "*is it really an int?*" is the same as "*is it not null?*".

This can be expressed more clearly as

```
private void DoStuff(int? a)
{
    int c = 0;
    if (a.HasValue)
    {
        c = a.Value;
    }
}
```

or shorter

```
private void DoStuff(int? a)
{
    int c = a.GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

to assign the default value (0) when `a` is null, or use the real value when not.