# Can I access an object that only exists within the condition in an if the condition is true?

Tags: c#, if-statement, pattern-matching

I am looking for something that resembles this.

```
if(obj is User user)
{
    user.FirstName = ...
}
```

Now I want the same only that I make a null check for example.
Currently I have to do the following.

```
User user;
if ((user = dbContext.Get<User>(id)) != null)
{
    user.FirstName = ...
}
```

Is there any way to get to the same result without the top row?

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71849590/how-should-i-interpret-the-null-check-pattern-in-c-sharp

Comment: Your first code block already does a null check: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KgmkYL

Answer (score 2):

You can just combine the two syntaxes. The existing `is` already does a `null` check.

```cs
if (dbContext.Get<User>(id) is User user)
{
    user.FirstName = ...
}
```

For more info, see how the C# compiler translates the `is` syntax. You can see the null check in action on [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRjkqQKoDOMUA/KQFkAhgGsYXHgAoAlKQC8APlIA7AK4AbdQG56jEuVbkUpAGIQIM0roZ0Cje6QCWAM1KThYiVEuPOHblCkqgHS1g62DpEGAJySAETKEAAuKhrqpHGkANRBAQB0AHJCALYw0jp2UQC+YTUEdYT6sJBQACb+PFYEEXpksACOqo6w7SwADKRFpbQA5jBJWo7Kjgt1VUA).

Comment: Thanks for that. Incidentally not sure why the decompilation has a `(object)` cast, there is none in the IL

Comment: The `(object)` cast is a C# representation (as it converted IL back to C#) of the fact that it's doing a reference check, not an `==` check that could invoke a custom equality operator if there is one.

Comment: I probably would have written it `if(!(user is null))` DotPeek just goes for `if (user == null)`

Comment: In C# 6, sure, but since the `not` pattern was introduced, now you have `if (user is not null)`. DotPeek may be doing it with the knowledge that there's no overloaded operator, so the resulting `==` will certainly be a reference test.